# Losing Data from bash Script in Java

Tags: java, bash

I am trying to get bash data into a variable. The problem is that it's so darn random.   The command executes every time, I can see that by having an X application start.  However my processor may be too fast or slow to issue the echo command and start a buffered read to the input stream.

How can I get this to work?  I need to issue the command inside a buffered reader somehow.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class test1 {

 public static void main() {

  try { 
   Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("echo Gosh, I sure hope this comes back to java");
   BufferedReader read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc
     .getInputStream()));

   while (read.ready()) {
    System.out.println(read.readLine());
   }
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println(e.getMessage());
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace your while loop with this:

```
String line;
while ((line = read.readLine())!=null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Either read [this](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html), or try [java.lang.Process](http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.lang/Exec.html).